# BlocBuilder only build once and stop rebuild with subsequent emit

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have an IconButton that click on it will pin/unpin the window, and the icon will change according to  pinned or not. The first click on the button will trigger a rebuild event, but subsequent click does not. And I have absolutely no idea on it.

I created a minimal example here: https://gist.github.com/TENX-S/7a811cb23b3b0ed220b75f4b2cda7fd3, for repo: https://github.com/TENX-S/miniexample

I tried to read documentation on https://bloclibrary.dev/, but I'm not getting the answer to it.

[image]

Comment: you have mutable state class. when you do `state..alwaysOnTop=pinned` it is changing value in current state. so emitted state is same as next state. hence not building.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance @Rahul! I thought mutating a state is making it different. Got to be more careful from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The problem is the implementation of SettingsCubit
- [Link to the output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ELd6kpA9JvsHs7IlnEJ28kL27M0w64HX/view?usp=drive_link)
- Below is my updated version of your settings.dart

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Settings {

  final bool alwaysOnTop;

  Settings({required this.alwaysOnTop});

  const Settings._({
    this.alwaysOnTop = false,
  });

  const Settings.initial() : this._();

  const Settings.update(bool onTop): this._(alwaysOnTop: onTop);

  factory Settings.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$SettingsFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$SettingsToJson(this);

}

class SettingsCubit extends HydratedCubit<Settings> {
  SettingsCubit() : super(const Settings.initial());

  set alwaysOnTop(bool pinned) => emit(Settings.update(pinned));

  bool get alwaysOnTop => state.alwaysOnTop;

  @override
  Settings? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Settings.fromJson(json);
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(Settings state) {
    return state.toJson();
  }
}
```

- your HomePage build method

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final settingsCubit = context.read<SettingsCubit>();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: IconButton(
          icon: settingsCubit.alwaysOnTop ? const Icon(FluentIcons.pin_24_filled): const Icon(FluentIcons.pin_24_regular),
          onPressed: () {
            settingsCubit.alwaysOnTop = !widget.pinned;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, @Sowat Kheang! Your code works like a charm! It seems that when emitting a state, we shouldn't directly mutate the current state and emit it, but to create a new state. Am I understanding this difference correctly?

Comment: Absolutely, yes. Just like @Rahul commented.